# React component does not render with curly brackets

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react component does not render with curly bracket and here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/21704/

```
class R1 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="r1">
                {this.props.data.map( datum => 
                    <h1 key={datum}> {datum} </h1>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class R2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="r2">
                {this.props.data.map( datum => {
                    <h1 key={datum}> {datum} </h1>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that the only difference between R1 and R2 component is that R1 does not use {} after "=>" in map, while R2 does. R1 works fine, but R2 does not render anything.

I am quite new to javascript and react (coming from C/C++), I thought for multi-line block, {} should be included. But it's obviously not working here.

Just wonders is this javascript specific syntax issue or something related to React? And what is the problem with using {} in functional mapping.

PS: In real code, I use immutable List rather than plain javascript list if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example's `map` callback does not return anything.

If your method body contains a single statement, you may omit the `{}` and the result of the expression will be returned. Using `x => x * 2` is fine, and will return a value.

If you include the`{}` around the method body, **you cannot omit the `return` keyword**, regardless of how many statements are inside the `{}`.  Using `x => { x * 2 }` does not return anything, as the method body contains no return statement.

By way of example:

```js
fn = x => x * 2
console.log(fn(3)) // 6

fn = x => { x * 2 }
console.log(fn(3)) // undefined

fn = x => { return x * 2 }
console.log(fn(3)) // 6
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using ES6 the main syntax would be like

```
functionName() => {
    /* Code/Actions goes here */
}
```

Comment: However, R2 does not render anything.

Comment: may be its because its an object or ur reading a wrong value?

Comment: This answer is wrong, the code in the question is syntactically fine. `x => { /* ... */ }` is just as valid ES6 syntax as `(x) => { /* ... */}`. When your function accepts one argument, you may omit the parenthesis around the argument.